# SQLite How to sum columns based on one one column and group based on a different column

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

For example, table TableQ looks like this:

| Item | Price | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 2 | X |
| Item A | 4 | Y |
| Item B | 1 | Z |

I want my output to be like this:

| Item | Price | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 6 | X |
| Item A | 6 | Y |
| Item B | 1 | Z |

When I try

select distinct * from TableQ as Q1
left join (
select
sum(Q2.Price) as PriceSum
from TableQ as Q2 )

I get

| Item | Price | Tag | PriceSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 2 | X | 7 |
| Item A | 4 | Y | 7 |
| Item B | 1 | Z | 7 |

Comment: you have to group by your subquery by item

Comment: When I group by Item, for some reason I lose the Tag uniqueness. I get

Item A > 6 > X
Item B > 1 > Z

Comment: only in your subquery

Comment: Thank you! That worked. For reference, this is the code
select distinct * from TableQ as Q1 left join ( select sum(Q2.Price) as PriceSum from TableQ group by Item ) as Q2 on Q2.Item = Q1.Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15)](https://sqlite.org/changes.html) SQLite supports window functions:

```
SELECT Item,
       SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) AS Price,
       Tag 
FROM TableQ;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fX_mKaHu).